# How to change to default english language?

Tags: language-support

I just accidentally set my Ubuntu to chinese and I don't understand anything that it says. This makes it difficult to change the language, although I had enter Locale to change the language because it's all in chinese. Does anyone know how can I change my Ubuntu's default language using the terminal?

Answer (score 3):

Change default language for the console :

Edit `/home/USERNAME/.bash_profile` file (create if not exist) and add the line `export LANG=de`(example given for German)

Comment: Can you post the specific instructions back into your answer, so there's no need to hunt for the correct OS or if the link breaks? Thanks!

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LocaleConf

That's more specific for Ubuntu, but the jest is that you can either do that or add the lines in the first link to your .profile file.
add:
export LANG=en

Comment: That's not what I meant. You shouldn't just post links to information, but include the specific steps to follow in your answer itself. See [this answer on StackOverflow Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) for more information on why you should do this.

Answer (score 0):

The default `locale` file location here:
**/etc/default**

Edit `locale` file like this and save:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Done. Now log-out and log-in.