# How to change from German to English in the File Manager in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10, language-support, filemanager

My months and days in my File Manager are in German, how do I change that?
On the photo you see 'Dez' : It means Dezember (German for December). I also saw one day Mittwoch (German for Wednesday). How do I change that German issue? This is only my File Manager and not completly but partially. Weird.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change to default english language?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/69761/how-to-change-to-default-english-language)

Comment: No, only my File Manager is partially German.

Comment: did you try to re-login or reboot after changing language settings?

Comment: Yes, I did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want various formats in English, and not only the language, open Language Support, go to "Regional Formats", and select some English formats option of your choice. Then relogin.

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-formats.html

Comment: I will try if it works.

Comment: Works!!! Finally!